# Handling 2 keys for same value in single class

Tags: json, swift, serialization, swifty-json

I have a use case in which I get score form JSON using

```
let score = json["score_test"].arrayValue.map {Score.decode(json: $0)}
```

I have to reuse this class for a response in which only **key** for the value changes i.e

```
let score = json["score"].arrayValue.map {Score.decode(json: $0)}
```

Is there a way to achieve this so that I get the data of Score **object** whether the key is **score_test** or **score** depending on the JSON using the same class?

Also I tried using nil check but since the object is initialized that is not working.

Model of Score:

```
class Score: Object, Decoder {

    dynamic var id:     String = ""
    dynamic var title:  String = ""
    dynamic var body:   String = ""
    dynamic var cardOrder: Int = 0

    dynamic var video:  Video? = nil

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    typealias T = Score

    // MARK: Decoder method
    static func decode(json: JSON) -> Score {
        let id = json["_id"].stringValue
        let title = json["title"].stringValue
        let body = json["data"].stringValue
        let cardOrder = json["card_order"].intValue

        var video: Video?
        if (json["video"].exists()) {
            video = Video.decode(json: json["video"])
        }

        let score = Score()
        score.id = id
        score.title = title
        score.body = body
        score.video = video
        score.cardOrder = cardOrder

        return score
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your model to see the type of score ?

Comment: What is `score` when you assign `json[“score_test”]` to it instead of `json[“score”]`, where you want to assign `json[“score”]`?

Comment: The value/result for json[“score_test”] and json[“score”] is same, in one api call I get the key as "score_test" while for a different call I get the key as "score".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, `score` is of type `[Score]` so what I'd do is:

```
var score = json["score_test"].arrayValue.map {Score.decode(json: $0)}

if score.isEmpty {
    score = json["score"].arrayValue.map {Score.decode(json: $0)}
}
```

Comment: If it was `Score` and not `[Score]`, I'd change your decode method in the model to return an optionnal `Score?` and do a nil check. Else add a method to your model returning a `Bool` to check if all values are empty.